# debug gogole analtyics 4 purchase not show up altough its a set up as event

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-ads-script, debugview

Hi I defined purcahse as event in google analytics 4 and while I check it im not seeing the purchase are working, i test it when i purchase someting but it not showng up could someone have an idea why isn't it show up on debug view? thank you (:[[
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oknyn.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFTLc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCcd0.png) thank you for answering (:

I'm trying to get the purchase to appear and be updated in google ads, and send the data, I'd be grateful to anyone who can help me with this. Thanks (:...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

For purchase event required event params are:

- currency
- value
- items
- transaction_id

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?sjid=3715847216967009504-EU&hl=ru&client_type=gtag#purchase
Are you sure that all of these params you send in Analytics?  Also, you can check the trigger for the purchase event (usually it visit "thank_you" page)